# Saved model trained with MirroredStrategy has poor performance when loaded

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, multi-gpu

I trained a UNet binary segmentation model using tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy with multi-gpu setup (2x NVidia 4090).  The model seems to work fine during the training since the dice loss gets improves from initial cca 0.8 to 0.1. I am using the ModelCheckpoint callback to save the best model from the training session. When I try to load the model from the .h5 file, the prediction output is very bad (only a few random pixels is segmented). (I even tried to use data from the validation set, that were previously successfully predicted during the training.) This behavior did not occur before I moved to the multi-gpu/MirroredStrategy setup. I tried both saving the model and saving only the model weights. Does anyone have any ideas, what can cause this issue?

This is my training function:

```
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
with strategy.scope():
  model = UNet(
               (image_width, image_height, 3), 
               batchnorm=True, 
               start_ch=start_channel_count, 
               depth=layer_count,     
               residual=use_residual)
  model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate), 
                loss=dice_coef_loss, metrics= 
                  [tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(), 
                  tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU(num_classes=2)])

def scheduler(epoch, lr):
  if epoch < 10:
      return lr
  else:
      return lr * tf.math.exp(-0.1)
mc = ModelCheckpoint(os.path.join(run_dir_path, "model.h5"), 
                     monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, 
                     save_benter code here`est_only=True, 
                     save_weights_only = True)

history = model.fit(train_data_generator,
                    validation_data=validation_data_generator,
                    callbacks=[mc], 
                    validation_steps=
                      math.ceil(validation_count/batch_size),
                    steps_per_epoch=
                      math.ceil(train_count / batch_size),
                    epochs=100)
```

Then when I try to do the evaluation of the trained model it works:

```
model.evaluate(validation_data, 
               steps=math.ceil(validation_count / batch_size))
```

When I try to perform the evaluation after loading the weights from the .h5 file, it performs badly:

```
model.load_weights(os.path.join(run_dir_path, "model.h5"))
model.evaluate(validation_data, 
               steps=math.ceil(validation_count / batch_size))
```

Comment: Can you add some more details in the question like snippets of your train and eval functions?

Comment: I edited the description of my issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the issue is because of training with MirroredStrategy. You can check this issue on official keras github - [model.evaluate() gives a different loss on training data from the one in training process](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6977#issuecomment-366567948)
.

Also try to use model.predict function to eval the model and write your own custom metric calculation to see if the results are consistent.

Comment: Thank You I inspected the the link. The issue is a bit different from mine. The evaluation outputs are not only a little different, but the model completely fails to output something meaningful. Both the "predict()" and "evaluate" fails. Exactly the same training session without the "MirroredStrategy" with 1 GPU is working though.